# Ajax crawlable with _escaped_fragment= with history HTML5

Tags: ajax, seo

I'm trying to understand how Google/Bing indexes Ajax content. I think my thought is pretty clear when using hashbang URL, but how does it work when you are using HTML5 PushState API ?

For instance, the following url www.exemple.com/foo is "transtaled" to www.exemple.com/foo?_escaped_fragment= by Google. But how about URLs that have GET parameters, like www.exemple.com/foo?page=4 ? Is it translated to www.exemple.com/foo?page=4&_escaped_fragment= ?

Thanks :).

Answer (score 0):

Yes _escaped_fragment is always added as the last parameter. Check the specification from google here https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/docs/specification

> Further, there must only be one _escaped_fragment_ in the URL, and it
>   must be the last query parameter

There is no difference between HTML5 and Hashbang in that case since you can have get parameters in both cases.

The only difference when using hashbang _escaped_fragment will contain the path whereas it will be empty when using html5.

Remark:
With html5 you need to put the following code in your html page because the search engine bot won't see any hashbang in your url:

```
<meta name="fragment" content="!">
```